# Reasoning behind this and scope (I think related to scope)

Tags: java

I'm coming to Java from Python and thought that `this` is basically like Python's `self`...but this small code confuses me. Functionally, this code:

```
public class Test {

    private String name;
    public Test(String givenName)
    {
        this.name = givenName;
    }
    public String nameGet()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Test example = new Test("Hello Guys");
        System.out.println(example.nameGet());

    }

}
```

does the same exact thing as this code:

```
public class Test {

private String name;
public Test(String givenName)
{
    name = givenName;
}
public String nameGet()
{
    return name;
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Test example = new Test("Hello Guys");
    System.out.println(example.nameGet());

}
```

}

Since this, pardon the pun, seems to be the case, what then is the point of referring to this when working within the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Test(String givenName)
{
    this.name = givenName;
}
```

The this. is not needed in this case or in the get method).  It is commonly used when the code is like this instead:

```
public Test(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
```

Which tells the compiler to set the instance variable (`this.name`) to the local variable (`name`).

Some people do it to be very clear that they are using an instance variable.

Comment: So the first constructor is doing what then? Since givenName isn't a local variable, what is happening?

Comment: given name is a local variable... it is a parameter to the constructor.  It will have the value "Hello Guys" in the code given in your example.

Answer (score 2):

It's often not needed but may be necessary in case of ambiguity.
Say your constructor parameter was called `name` then there would be no way of determining which variable you're referring to.
Thus you would have to use:

```
public class Test {
  private String name;
  public Test(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

(On a side note; if you'll ever work with inner classes and you've got name ambiguity you use OuterClass.this:

```
public class Test {
  private String name;
  private class InnerTest {
    InnerTest(String name) {
      Test.this.name = name;
    }
  }
  public Test(String name) {
    new InnerTest(name);
  }
}
```